# What is the corresponding LAPACK function behind Matlab sum(A,2), in which A is matrix?

Tags: matlab, lapack

What is the corresponding LAPACK function behind Matlab function `sum(A,2)`, in which `A` is matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look at the [LAPACK documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/).  I've also taken a look at [this post on Computational Science beta](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/blas-lapack-non-absolute-sum).  It turns out that there is no native LAPACK function that will compute a sum of a matrix in a given dimension.  As such, MATLAB probably wrote something custom in order to facilitate the sum over a given dimension of a matrix in this fashion.

There are a few of ways to go around this though:

1. Compute a matrix-vector multiplication with a vector of all 1s.  Because you're doing `sum(A,2)`, this means that you want to sum over all of the columns for each row.  You can encapsulate this behaviour by doing `y = A*x`, where `A` is the matrix in question and `x` is a vector of all 1s.  `y` would be the output where you would retrieve the sum over all columns for each row in the matrix. As such, you can use [`sgemv`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d58/sgemv_8f.html) and carefully choosing the right inputs so that the vector `x` consists of all 1s, and the matrix `A` is the matrix in question.  You need to set the `beta` constant to be 0, and supply the `y` vector to be all zeroes.  You would also need to set `alpha` equal to 1.
2. You can opt to write your own code that loops over all of the columns for each row in your matrix and add all of the elements together.  If you try to do Option #1, this operation doesn't allow for any cache reuse.  As such, most compilers should be able to optimize the code to the best possible performance when you're writing your own loop.
3. Another method would be to extract each row of your matrix as a vector and compute the dot product with this row with a vector of all 1s.  Perhaps using something like [`sdsdot`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d47/sdsdot_8f_source.html) would do the trick.

However, if your code isn't spending much time doing sums, then you can opt for Option #1.  If you are repeatedly doing `sum(A,2)` calculations, then it's best to write your own loop to do it (i.e. Options #2 or #3).

Good luck!